# iOS - Alamofire - cannot reach server on WiFi

Tags: ios, networking, dns, alamofire

I am slowly distributing my app to Beta testers via TestFlight.

A few of them have already reported that the app showed “No Internet connection” while on WiFi. As soon as they switched to cellular everything started to work. The WiFi works for everything else.

I use Alamofire as a framework to make HTTPRequests and when these requests fail, “No Internet connection” error is displayed.

- My backend service is hosted on Google Cloud
- My domain is registered using AWS Route 53
- I use SSL certificates managed by Google

All HTTPRequests are sent to https://api.myapp.com (where myapp.com is hosted on AWS).

All of the testers have Automatic DNS resolution set in Settings -> WiFi -> (i) -> DNS

Any ideas what the cause can be or how I can further investigate this issue?

This is the piece of code used to make GET requests:

```swift
    func getJSON(_ url: String,
                 parameters: [String: String] = [:],
                 headers: [String: String] = [:],
                 completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: JSON?,
                                               _ headers: [String: String]?,
                                               _ statusCode: Int?,
                                               _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        
        Self.sessionManager.request(
            url,
            method: .get,
            parameters: parameters,
            headers: self.createHeaders(headers: headers),
            interceptor: self,
            requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = HttpClient.defaultTimeoutInterval }
        ).validate().responseJSON { response in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                completionHandler(json, self.getResponseHeaders(httpUrlResponse: response.response), response.response?.statusCode, nil)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, self.getResponseHeaders(httpUrlResponse: response.response), response.response?.statusCode, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

The connection error is displayed when `error != nil`. When it happens, it happens for all HTTP endpoints (does not matter if an endpoint requires authentication or authorization, all HTTP requests fail).

Comment: What triggers the "no internet connection" message in your app?  Is it in response to an error or do you check for connectivity somehow? Is the error actually no connection or do you display that message regardless of the actual error?  Can you send them a build that produces a more meaningful message; perhaps the actual error code and/or response that is received?

Comment: @Paulw11 It is in response to an error coming from an HTTPRequest. I added the source code. As I mentioned already, the weird thing is that it works while using cellular, but doesn't while on WiFi. Thus I think everything is fine with the HTTPRequest itself and the problem lies in networking

Comment: As I said, I would start by releasing a build for the testers that shows more information; what was the exact http response and error that was received. There are literally a million things that can go wrong on network requests; firewalls, DNS failures, routing failures, DOS prevention...

Comment: I agree that many things go wrong there. How can I log errors when the app is released? Did you mean just like an alert presented to the user with technical details of why a request failed? So far I have been mostly debugging errors while running from Xcode so I usually just printed them in the console.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. You can also use `MFMailComposeViewController` to create an email that they can send to you. That way you can include as much detail as you need.  Without more detail and without access to a network that has the problem yourself you are working in the dark.  Obviously you can take this out prior to general release

Comment: Ok, many thanks for pointing me into that direction! I already have a lot of logic for saving/loading entities on/from iPhone's disk so I think I will just dump the HTTP errors to disk and provide a way to send them to me (let's say when they switch to cellular or to copy+paste it and send via email). I will create another section in settings for managing these. I will disable this section before the general release.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237068/discussion-between-koles-and-paulw11).